# How to draw a circle at given position?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a canvas 200x200 pixels, and I want to put a red circle with radius = 10 at position (45, 33).
How do I do that?

I can of course select Ellipse tool, move mouse across canvas until Info window coordinates become (45, 33) and then click, but I hope there should exist simpler method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw and select the shape

In Edit menu select Free Transform

On the Option bar type the coordinates into the horizontal and
vertical position boxes

Right click on the boxes to change the unit of measure

Press Enter to apply